# Symfony2 Best Practices confusion

Tags: symfony

I was going through the Symfony2 best practices and got confused on two things:

1 - Annotation usage - It says that for Routing and Cache we should use Annotations. But, I prefer to use annotations for ORM & Validation and YAML for Routing (one single file for all routes). How it is a bad practice?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#routing-configuration

2 - For reusable bundle (never created one), if I wish to include any JS library like jQuery then it's not a good practice? Confused.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#vendors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that "Best Practice" doesn't mean that doing anything different from what's suggested is wrong. Instead, anything is perfect if you know why you're doing it. The Best Practice guide is designed to take away some decisions for beginners. They already have a hard time learning the framework, having to make decisions like where to put code and which format to use would make things infinitely more difficult.

With that in mind, the reasons for the best practices you mentioned:

> 1 - Annotation usage - It says that for Routing n Cache we should use Annotations. But, I prefer to use annotations for ORM & Validation and YAML for Routing (one single file for all routes). How it is a bad practice? http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#routing-configuration

Having less files makes it easier to follow what's going on. Imagine having a route, controller, an entity and some validation. This means that one has to learn the following locations: `app/config/routing.yml`, `src/AppBundle/Controller/StaticController.php`, `src/AppBundle/Entity/SomeEntity.php`, `src/AppBundle/config/validation.yml` and `src/AppBundle/config/doctrine/SomeEntity.orm.yml`. That's quite a big list to get familair with.

If Symfony recommends to use annotations for everything, you end up with the following list: `src/AppBundle/Controller/StaticController.php`, `src/AppBundle/Entity/SomeEntity.php`. That's quite an improvement. This is the reason that Symfony recommends to use annotations *if you're starting to learn the framework*. If you're familiar with Symfony, you probably make your own choices and decide which format you like and which you don't like (some people like annotations, others hate them and prefer XML or YAML).

> 2 - For reusable bundle (never created one), if I wish to include any JS library like jQuery then it's not a good practice? Confused. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#vendors

It's often not very great to commit dependencies. For that reason, Composer was created. For front-end dependencies, Bower/BowerPHP was created. Using something like that means your code is easier to share.

Of course, as Symfony is a back-end framework, it's perfectly fine to use jQuery or whatever library you like.

Comment: Thanks for such an awesome explanation. This is my first framework and I am seriously in love with Symfony2. I hope I will be good with this in next 5-6 months. :)

Comment: @Wouter-j ok, but isn't YML / XML better for reusable bundles, especially for a Model (e.g. Entities), since it allows to put your ORM or Validation config anywhere, also in your app's bundle that uses the original reusable bundle where the Model comes from? Especially, when you want to stay storage-agnostic, like in e.g. FOS User Bundle?

Answer (score 2):

1.that say:

> Make your controller extend the FrameworkBundle base controller and use annotations to configure routing, caching and security whenever possible.

for that you have thin controller and you can only have routing & caching & security in your controller as annotaion.

orm mapping & validation are in entities no in controller

and that say:

> In addition, using annotations for routing, caching and security simplifies configuration. You don't need to browse tens of files created with different formats (YAML, XML, PHP): all the configuration is just where you need it and it only uses one format.

because, routing & security & caching are related to a controller, but orm mapping & validation are diffrence and can use in onther places(controllers, repositories, services and ...)

2.

> For reusable bundle (never created one), if I wish to include any JS library like JQuery then it is not good practice

and if you will use third-party bundles, that is better that you use a depedency manager as composer or bower.

see [sonata admin bundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/tree/2.3) that is a good & big project that use bower for third-party bundles as jquery, bootstrap & ...

Comment: So Routing should be done using Annotations? As a professional, do you use the same things/standards as mentioned in the best practices?

Comment: no, that article no say that you must use annotation, that say that you can use annotaion for that you can have all things in a place and have a good view

Comment: One more que. not related to above one. i wish to become a good PHP programmer and learning Symfony2 n related techs. Do i need to learn multiple frameworks to be good? I am a freelancer. Thanks

Comment: no, instead of learn multiplie framework. i suggest that you learn symfony very good(all component & kernel) and try write code with good style (http://www.php-fig.org) & good documented ;)